# Set bulletBorderColor to lineColor by default in amCharts

Tags: javascript, json, charts, amcharts

[According to the amCharts documentation, if bulletBorderColor isn't set, it will default to lineColor.](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletBorderColor) This doesn't seem to be working. I am building a theme for my team to use so they don't have to worry about setting colors every time they generate a chart. Does anyone have a workaround, or solution for this?

**CodePen:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwByvL

**Code:**

```
AmCharts.makeChart("line-chart-fw", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "sailthru",
  "marginTop": 0,
  "marginRight": 0,
  "marginLeft": 0,
  "marginBottom": 0,
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "pathToImages": "js/amcharts/images/",
  "graphs": [{
    "title": "Yesterday",
    "id": "g2",
    "balloonText": "",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "value2"
  }, {
    "title": "Today",
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]</b><br><span style='font-size:11px;'>Today: [[value]]</span><br><span style='font-size:11px;'>Yesterday: [[value2]]</span>",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "value"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": false,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": false,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
    "fullWidth": true,
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "marginTop": 0,
    "marginBottom": 0,
    "width": 140,
    "labelText": "[[title]]",
    "valueText": "",
  },
  "categoryField": "year",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": false,
    "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
    "labelsEnabled": true,
    "inside": false,
  },

  "dataProvider": [{
    "year": "12 AM",
    "value": 5,
    "value2": 10
  }, {
    "year": "1 AM",
    "value": 10,
    "value2": 5
  }, {
    "year": "2 AM",
    "value": 15,
    "value2": 20
  }, {
    "year": "3 AM",
    "value": 5,
    "value2": 10
  }, {
    "year": "4 AM",
    "value": 12,
    "value2": 18
  }, {
    "year": "5 AM",
    "value": 16,
    "value2": 12
  }, {
    "year": "6 AM",
    "value": 7,
    "value2": 5
  }, {
    "year": "7 AM",
    "value": 20,
    "value2": 15
  }, {
    "year": "8 AM",
    "value": 25,
    "value2": 20
  }, {
    "year": "9 AM",
    "value": 20,
    "value2": 15
  }, {
    "year": "10 AM",
    "value": 20,
    "value2": 8
  }, {
    "year": "11 AM",
    "value": 60,
    "value2": 45
  }, {
    "year": "12 PM",
    "value": 80,
    "value2": 70
  }, {
    "year": "1 PM",
    "value": 95,
    "value2": 80
  }, {
    "year": "2 PM",
    "value": 80,
    "value2": 90
  }, {
    "year": "3 PM",
    "value": 40,
    "value2": 50
  }, {
    "year": "4 PM",
    "value": 60,
    "value2": 20
  }, {
    "year": "5 PM",
    "value2": 35
  }, {
    "year": "6 PM",
    "value2": 20
  }, {
    "year": "7 PM",
    "value2": 10
  }, {
    "year": "8 PM",
    "value2": 20
  }, {
    "year": "9 PM",
    "value2": 5
  }, {
    "year": "10 PM",
    "value2": 5
  }, {
    "year": "11 PM",
    "value2": 10

  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "labelsEnabled": true,
    "inside": true,
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
    "axisTitleOffset": 0,
    "maximum": 100,
  }]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation might not be very straightforward. Technically bullet border will use line's color, but only if you do not override the bullet color with `bulletColor`, which you seem to be doing.

To work around that use [`useLineColorForBulletBorder`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#useLineColorForBulletBorder). (set it to true)

So the relevant part of your theme file should look like this:

```
AmGraph: {
    lineAlpha: 1,
    bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
    bulletColor: "#ffffff",
    lineThickness: 1.5,
    fillAlphas: 0.05,
    bulletSize: 6,
    bulletBorderThickness: 1.5,
    bulletColor: "#ffffff",
    bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
    bullet: "round",
    minorGridEnabled: false,
    useLineColorForBulletBorder: true
}
```

P.S. I noticed you have a lot of trailing commas in your theme file (a comma after the last property in the object). While modern browsers can handle it, some older ones will fail with a syntax error. You might want to get that fixed.